# Recursive integration by parts

Tags: calculus, integration, integration-by-parts

I'm trying to integrate the product of an exponential and trigonometric function using integration by parts.
However, after 2 loops I realized that it would keep looping forever.

Is there any way to integrate this function?
$$\int_0^\pi e^{2t}\sin t dt$$

This are my attempt (I hope the picture and my writing is clear enough to be read):

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recursive integration by parts](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1696707/recursive-integration-by-parts)

Answer (score 2):

First, expand the integral using integration by parts until it reappears:

$$\begin{align*}
\int e^{2t} \sin{t} \ dt & ~=~ \frac{1}{2} e^{2t} \sin{t} - \frac{1}{2} \int e^{2t} \cos{t} \ dt \\
& ~=~ \frac{1}{2} e^{2t}\sin{t} - \frac{1}{4} e^{2t}\cos{t} - \frac{1}{4} \int e^{2t} \sin{t} \ dt
\end{align*}$$

Now combine like terms and multiply by $4 / 5$ to obtain:

$$\begin{align*}
\int e^{2t} \sin{t} \ dt & ~=~ \frac{2}{5} e^{2t}\sin{t} - \frac{1}{5} e^{2t} \cos{t} \\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Plus the constant of integration, "+c"